# Read/Extract .ppt Document all text using c#

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, powerpoint

I want to extract all the text from the document .ppt file.

I need some free library or some code to read/extract the .ppt document.

The soultion should not dependent of Ms.Office.

: dont want to use Microsoft Office Interop and IFilter

Answer (score 1):

Hey take a look at the following library:

[Aspose.com](http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx)

https://github.com/asposeslides/Aspose_Slides_NET

you can take a look at these also:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C

http://www.citeknet.com/Products/IFilters/IFilterExplorer/tabid/62/Default.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691105%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I need some "FREE" library.

Comment: Try following ALL the links.