# Extract all content of currently opened PowerPoint presentation and convert it into MemoryStream using C#

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, openxml, office-addins

I am working on Office AddIn project. I have created a `PowerPoint AddIn`. All functionalities working fine except one. I need to extract the content of all slides and save them into `MemoryStream`. I am able to fetch all the content of Word document by `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML` line. But somehow I am not able to get all the content same as Word AddIn.

Now I am clueless that how to fetch all the contents in OpenXML format. Any suggestions about how to fetch them?

Comment: I've done a quick google and there is already a topic about it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169661/read-extract-ppt-document-all-text-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Budyn I have tried aspose's APIs.I guess they are not providing to access currently open presentation's content, and by content I mean, everything like Image, audio, video, text etc.. Correct me if I'm wrong.